# Cleaning the external libraries in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

In my intellij sbt project I have added a dependency for com.crealytics
libraryDependencies += "com.crealytics" %% "spark-excel" % "0.10.2".

Everytime I am building the project its creating 2 libraries for commons-compress jar
I have tried to clean and build , close and reopen intellij , but nothing fixes this.

How can I clean up the library (not sure if it caches it somewhere) and rebuild , so that duplicate dependencies are removed?

[image: screnshoot attached]

My build.sbt refers to a dependencies.scala file, here is how the dependencies are mentioned

```html
object versions {
    lazy val breeze:           String = "1.0-RC2"
    lazy val deequ:            String = "1.0.1"
    lazy val doobie:           String = "0.8.0-RC1"
    lazy val grizzledSlf4j:    String = "1.3.4"
    lazy val hadoopAws:        String = "2.7.3"
    lazy val hadoopHdfs:       String = "2.7.3"
    lazy val httpClient:       String = "4.5.6"
    lazy val httpCore:         String = "4.4.10"
    lazy val ibmCosSdk:        String = "2.5.2"
    lazy val jodaConvert:      String = "1.8.1"
    lazy val jodaTime:         String = "2.10.1"
    lazy val json4sNative:     String = "3.6.0-M2"
    lazy val kafka:            String = "2.3.0"
    lazy val mysqlConn:        String = "8.0.17"
    lazy val pureConfig:       String = "0.11.1"
    lazy val requests:         String = "0.1.9"
    lazy val scalactic:        String = "3.2.0-SNAP10"
    lazy val scalikeJdbc:      String = "3.4.0-RC1"
    lazy val scopt:            String = "4.0.0-RC2"
    lazy val slf4jSimple:      String = "1.8.0-beta2"
    lazy val sourceCode:       String = "0.1.5"
    lazy val spark:            String = "2.4.4"
    lazy val sparkExcel:       String = "0.10.2"
    lazy val sparkMeasures:    String = "0.14"
    lazy val sparkTestingBase: String = "2.4.3_0.12.0"
    lazy val stocator:         String = "1.0.29-IBM-SDK"
    lazy val ujson:            String = "0.7.4"
    lazy val awsJavaSdk:       String = "1.7.4"
    lazy val tika:             String = "1.21"

  }

  val framelessVersion: String = "0.8.0"

  lazy val breeze:           ModuleID = "org.scalanlp"              %% "breeze"              % versions.breeze
  lazy val deequ:            ModuleID = "com.amazon.deequ"          % "deequ"                % versions.deequ
  lazy val doobie:           ModuleID = "org.tpolecat"              %% "doobie-core"         % versions.doobie
  lazy val doobieScalaTest:  ModuleID = "org.tpolecat"              %% "doobie-scalatest"    % versions.doobie % Test
  lazy val framelessCats:    ModuleID = "org.typelevel"             %% "frameless-cats"      % framelessVersion
  lazy val framelessDataset: ModuleID = "org.typelevel"             %% "frameless-dataset"   % framelessVersion
  lazy val framelessML:      ModuleID = "org.typelevel"             %% "frameless-ml"        % framelessVersion
  lazy val grizzledLogging:  ModuleID = "org.clapper"               %% "grizzled-slf4j"      % versions.grizzledSlf4j
  lazy val hadoopAws:        ModuleID = "org.apache.hadoop"         % "hadoop-aws"           % versions.hadoopAws
  lazy val hadoopHdfs:       ModuleID = "org.apache.hadoop"         % "hadoop-hdfs"          % versions.hadoopHdfs
  lazy val httpClient:       ModuleID = "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient"           % versions.httpClient
  lazy val httpCore:         ModuleID = "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpcore"             % versions.httpCore
  lazy val httpMime:         ModuleID = "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpmime"             % versions.httpClient
  lazy val ibmCosSdk:        ModuleID = "com.ibm.cos"               % "ibm-cos-java-sdk"     % versions.ibmCosSdk
  lazy val jodaConvert:      ModuleID = "org.joda"                  % "joda-convert"         % versions.jodaConvert
  lazy val jodaTime:         ModuleID = "joda-time"                 % "joda-time"            % versions.jodaTime
  lazy val json4s:           ModuleID = "org.json4s"                %% "json4s-native"       % versions.json4sNative
  lazy val kafka:            ModuleID = "org.apache.kafka"          % "kafka-clients"        % versions.kafka
  lazy val kafkaSparkSql:    ModuleID = "org.apache.spark"          % "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % versions.spark
  lazy val mysqlConnector:   ModuleID = "mysql"                     % "mysql-connector-java" % versions.mysqlConn
  lazy val pureConfig:       ModuleID = "com.github.pureconfig"     %% "pureconfig"          % versions.pureConfig
  lazy val requests:         ModuleID = "com.lihaoyi"               %% "requests"            % versions.requests
  lazy val scalactic:        ModuleID = "org.scalactic"             %% "scalactic"           % versions.scalactic
  lazy val scalikeJdbc:      ModuleID = "org.scalikejdbc"           %% "scalikejdbc"         % versions.scalikeJdbc
  lazy val scopt:            ModuleID = "com.github.scopt"          %% "scopt"               % versions.scopt
  lazy val sourceCode:       ModuleID = "com.lihaoyi"               %% "sourcecode"          % versions.sourceCode
  lazy val sparkCore:        ModuleID = "org.apache.spark"          %% "spark-core"          % versions.spark % "provided"
  lazy val sparkExcel:       ModuleID = "com.crealytics"            %% "spark-excel"         % versions.sparkExcel
  lazy val sparkHive:        ModuleID = "org.apache.spark"          %% "spark-hive"          % versions.spark % Test exclude ("org.apache.hadoop", "*")
  lazy val sparkMeasures:    ModuleID = "ch.cern.sparkmeasure"      %% "spark-measure"       % versions.sparkMeasures
  lazy val sparkSql:         ModuleID = "org.apache.spark"          %% "spark-sql"           % versions.spark % "provided"
  lazy val sparkTestingBase: ModuleID = "com.holdenkarau"           %% "spark-testing-base"  % versions.sparkTestingBase % Test exclude ("com.fasterxml.jackson.core", "jackson-annotations") exclude ("com.fasterxml.jackson.core", "jackson-core") exclude ("com.fasterxml.jackson.core", "jackson-databind") exclude ("org.apache.hadoop", "*")
  lazy val stocator:         ModuleID = "com.ibm.stocator"          % "stocator"             % versions.stocator
  lazy val uJson:            ModuleID = "com.lihaoyi"               %% "ujson"               % versions.ujson
  lazy val tika:             ModuleID = "org.apache.tika"           % "tika-core"            % versions.tika
  lazy val awsJavaSdk = "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % versions.awsJavaSdk

  lazy val jacksonOverrides: List[ModuleID] = List(
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind"    % "2.6.5",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core"        % "2.6.5",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-annotations" % "2.6.5"
  )
```

Comment: Could you share you build.sbt file?

Comment: have edited the post